# Why Service runs only when app is running

Tags: android

I have below Service

```
public class service extends IntentService{

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private Editor editor;
    Timer timer;


    public service(String name) {
        super("Ali");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public service() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super("Ali");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        sp = getSharedPreferences("sp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();
        timer = new Timer();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    }
```

Declaration in manifest file

```
 <service android:name="ir.aiga.apps.ibrahim_hadi.services.service" 
        android:exported="false"/>
```

I use this code for start service in Activity

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, service.class));
```

But service just runs When application running.
What's problem?
Could it be for another application has a service name similar to my service name?

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` will automatically destroy() once its processing is completed. To run the service in background continuously use normal `Service`

Comment: I had timer.schedule in it

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that in another application a service name exist same present service name. I should change the service name.

Comment: The same name, including the same package name? That sounds highly unlikely.

Comment: No, exist another app with different package name, but same supur("Ali") in service

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#IntentService(java.lang.String)) the name passed in the constructor is "Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging."

Answer (score 0):

The `IntentService` will stop itself once all intents have been processed by `onHandleIntent()`

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> This method is invoked on the worker thread with a request to process. Only one Intent is processed at a time, but the processing happens on a worker thread that runs independently from other application logic. So, if this code takes a long time, it will hold up other requests to the same IntentService, but it will not hold up anything else. When all requests have been handled, the IntentService stops itself, so you should not call stopSelf().

My guess is that you're only starting the service once from your `Activity` in which case, once execution reaches the end of `onHandleIntent()` the `service` will stop itself, **regardless** of what else you're doing in that class.